# How to create multiple list depending on data retrieved?

Tags: list, windows-phone-7, listview, xml-parsing

I am consuming a webservice for getting the data and i am success fully getting back the data

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{ String username = txtblock4.Text.Trim();
String hash = txtblock8.Text.Trim();
client.UploadStringAsync(new    
Uri("http://www.picturelove.mobi/picturelove3/getmessages.php?loginType=N&email=" +   
username + "&hash=" + hash), "Post");
client.UploadStringCompleted += new   
UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_UploadStringCompleted);
}
```

I am parsing the xml response like below with two functions save message data  and generate message data i am gettin the data in a list.

```
void client_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{

if (e.Error != null)
txtblock10.Text = e.Error.Message.Trim();
else
txtblock10.Text = e.Result.Trim();
String XmlString = txtblock10.Text.Trim();
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(XmlString)))
{

while (reader.ReadToFollowing("all_messages"))
{
while (reader.Read())
{
try
{
reader.ReadToFollowing("id");
string id = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

reader.MoveToAttribute("from");
string n_from = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

reader.MoveToAttribute("to");
string n_to = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

reader.MoveToAttribute("time");
string n_time = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

reader.MoveToAttribute("sub");
string n_sub = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

reader.MoveToAttribute("ct");
string n_ct = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

reader.MoveToAttribute("txt");
string n_txt = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

reader.MoveToAttribute("msg_image");
string n_image = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

reader.MoveToAttribute("gender");
string n_gender = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

reader.MoveToAttribute("name");
string n_name = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

reader.MoveToAttribute("avatar");
string n_avatar = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
ObservableCollection<SampleData> dataSource = new ObservableCollection<SampleData>();
dataSource.Add(new SampleData() { Name = txtblock11.Text, Text = txtblock12.Text, 
Time= txtblock13.Text, Picture = txtblock9.Text });
// listBox.Items.Add(new SampleData() { Name = txtblock11.Text, Text = txtblock8.Text,                 
Time = txtblock5.Text, Picture = txtblock12.Text });
SaveMessageData(new SampleData() { Name = txtblock11.Text, Text = txtblock12.Text, Time     
= txtblock13.Text, Picture = txtblock9.Text });
// listBox1.ItemsSource =
this.GenerateMessageData();
}
catch
{
//MessageBox.Show("No New Messages For You", "No Message", MessageBoxButton.OK);
break;
}
}
}
}
}
}
public class SampleData
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Text { get; set; }
public string Time { get; set; }
public string Picture { get; set; }
}
public void SaveMessageData()
{
using (var isoStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
using (var isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("MyTextfile.txt", FileMode.Append,             
isoStorage))
    {
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<SampleData>));
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings))
{
List<SampleData> data = new List<SampleData>();
foreach (SampleData obj in Listbox.Items)
{
data.Add(obj);


}

data.Add(msg);
if (data != null)
serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, data);

}
}
}

}
}

public void GenerateMessageData()
{

List<SampleData> data;// = new List<SampleData>();
try
{
using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage =     
IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("MyTextfile.txt",     
 FileMode.Open))
{
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<SampleData>));
data = (List<SampleData>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
this.Listbox.ItemsSource = data;
return data;
}
}
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
MessageBox.Show("No New Messages For You", "No Message", MessageBoxButton.OK);
}
return null;
}
```

But, The real problem is if there are two set of data(two messages) if i'm getting both are showing in the same list. How to manipulate or iterate  multiple lists if there are multiple data?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to merge two lists and there may be items which exist in both but you only want to appear in the merged list once, the easiest solution is to simply check if it's already in the list before adding it.